# Create thumbnails from URLs using PHP

Tags: php, html, web

I want to generate thumbnails of websites. I found a few sites that handle it with an API, such as http://www.websnapr.com/

How can this be done with PHP so I can handle all of the requests on my server?

Comment: Related reading: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/instant-previews-under-hood.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP can't do this on it's own as it does not include an HTML rendering library.

You can find an external method of capturing the screenshots and communicate with that method using PHP, though.

First you'll need a system set up to take screenshots. Look into IECapt (http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/), CutyCapt (http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) or khtml2png (http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/) and configure one of those on a system.

Then set up a PHP script that will exec() the screenshot taking application and return the data to the browser.

For example:

```
<?php
$in_url = 'http://' . $_REQUEST['url']; // !!INSECURE!! In production, make sure to sanitize this input!
$filename = '/var/cutycapt/images/' . $_REQUEST['url'] . '.png'; // Will probably need to normalize filename too, this is just an illustration

// First check the file does not exist, if it does exist skip generation and reuse the file
// This is a super simple caching system that will help to reduce the resource requirements
if(!file_exists($filename)) {
  exec('/usr/local/bin/CutyCapt --url="' . $_REQUEST['url'] . '" --out="' . $filename . '"');
}

// Second check if the file exists, either from a previous run or from the above generation routine
if(file_exists($filename)) {
  header('Content-type: image/png');
  print file_get_contents($filename);
} else {
  header('Status: 500 Internal Server Error');
}
?>
```

You can then call the script in the following way:

```
http://localhost/screenshot.php?url=www.google.com
```

Building the screenshots is going to be CPU intensive so I'd strongly recommend building in some kind of file caching (ie. save the results of the output and check to see if you already have a screenshot somewhere), perhaps even a queuing system so your screenshot server does not get overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1):

Answer depends on which platform you are using. Anyways, here is this [question asked before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686858/web-page-screenshots-with-php)

If you want to create headless (no screen) commandline based screenshots, most aproaches involve Xvfb in some way, and/or installing a lot of dependencies/libraries.

**linux:**

khtml2png.sourceforge.net

mysql-apache-php.com/website_screenshot.htm

cutycapt.sourceforge.net

www.unruhdesigns.com/news/2010/10/using-firefox-on-a-headless-server-to-make-screenshots-of-websites

**windows:**

iecapt.sourceforge.net

**mac:**

www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/

EDIT: It's more than posible on something like rackspace of course, and on any shared host that lets you compile and install your own code, like webfaction.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid php is not able to handle such tasks on its own. You have to install some external libraries on server.

Possible related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686858/web-page-screenshots-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Tim is probably right, you can't do something like that on a shared host.

An implementation I've done was used on a dedicated linux server and it featured [Xvfb](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.1/Xvfb.1.html), firefox and the import command.

You might also want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux)