# How to take screenshot of whole web page, rather than what shows on the screen

Tags: image

I have a web page that doesnt fit screen in normal resolution, so I have to scroll to view it all. I want to take a screenshot that captures the whole page, and not just what shows on the screen. How can I do that.

Currently, I press F11, then zoom out till the whole page fits one screen (and consequently no scrollbar shows), then I press printscreen. I want to be able to capture the whole web page without needing to zoom out and without it fitting the screen, so that the image will have more detail and would be longer. Is there any free tool that can do that, or is there a paid tool for it? Or is there a simple shortcut to do that?

Edit: My current problem is solved as I am using Screengrab to capture web screenshots now. But is there a more general tool that will capture screenshots of other documents like adobe documents?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming?  Something tells me it doesn't.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [Screengrab Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146).

Comment: It doesn't work with new Firefox versions.

Answer (score 69):

There was a similar question here: [Take a full page screenshot with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158083/take-a-full-page-screenshot-with-firefox).

To summarize, in recent versions of Firefox you can grab the whole web page in two steps:

1. **Shift+F2** (this opens up the Firefox console)
2. `screenshot --fullpage`

Comment: This works great and without plugins. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Wonderful. It's really simple.

Answer (score 5):

I use [Snagit!](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp) for that.

Comment: see "capture a tall window" here: http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/features.asp

Comment: Anyone care to explain the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I didn't downvote, but snagit is very intrusive on the machine.  It will hijack shortcuts of other programs and even the operating system itself.  Try opening Eclipse and snag it at the same time and using your favorite shortcuts.

Comment: @KevinBowersox: I've found that I can turn off any Snagit shortcuts that get in my way.

Answer (score 4):

There are [a lot of Firefox plugins to do this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-cool-firefox-extensions-to-capture-screens/).

Answer (score 3):

Try the [screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146) firefox plugin. It allows you to do that (complete page/frame screenshot). 
(Oops.. somebody beat me to that answer)

Answer (score 3):

There's also this great product called [ScreenshotCaptor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html) which does this and a whole lot more. You can get a free registration key from the product website.

Answer (score 2):

Use firefox [Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146). There is an option to grab entier page.

Answer (score 2):

There's a free version (5.3) of FastStone Capture that I would highly recommend. Allows you to do scrolling, full window, drawn areas etc as well as annotations and color grabs with a very minimalist interface, I find SnagIt to be a bit much..

b

Answer (score 0):

One can use [fireshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fireshot/developers) for this as well... 
Hope, will help someone.

Comment: I think a flag on the question because it asks for a tool recommendation would have been a  better action.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome, you can use the extension:

[full-page-screen-capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Comment: The question is off-topic, better not add answer those.

Comment: In what is it off-topic ? The solution was proposed on a firefox plugin, and I gave a Google Chrome alternative.

Comment: Please visit the [help]. *4.Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*