# Take a full page screenshot with Firefox on the command-line

Tags: shell, firefox, command-line, screenshot

I'm running Firefox on a Xvfb in a VPS. What I want to do is to take a full page screenshot of the page.

I can redirect Firefox to particular page using

```
firefox http://google.com
```

and take a screenshot (inside X) using ImageMagick

```
import root -window output.jpg
```

The problem is, most of the page need scrolling and I can't know the height beforehand.

The other way is to pick a very big height (like 4000px) and then process the image and remove the useless part. But that's unnecessary processing.

I found many Firefox add-ons, but I'm looking for a solution that can be programmed using the Shell Command line.

Edit: I ended up writing my own [FireFox extension](https://github.com/omarabid/CmdShots) for doing this.

Comment: I've seen some webkit cli tools for take screenshots but I don't remember the names.

Answer (score 499, accepted):

The [Developer Toolbar GCLI and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut were removed in Firefox version 60](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/firefox-dev/2018-March/006249.html). To take a screenshot in 60 or newer:

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to open the developer console (<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on macOS)
- type `:screenshot` or `:screenshot --fullpage`

[Find out more regarding screenshots and other features](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2018/08/23/screenshots-from-the-console/)

---

For Firefox versions < 60:

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or go to **Tools > Web Developer > Developer Toolbar** to open a command line. Write:

```
screenshot
```

and press **Enter** in order to take a screenshot.

To fully answer the question, you can even save the whole page, not only the visible part of it:

```
screenshot --fullpage
```

And to copy the screenshot to clipboard, use `--clipboard` option:

```
screenshot --clipboard --fullpage
```

[Firefox 18](http://support.mozilla.org/es/questions/947227) changes the way arguments are passed to commands, you have to add "--" before them.

[Firefox 88.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158083/take-a-full-page-screenshot-with-firefox-on-the-command-line/14830242?noredirect=1#comment118932922_14830242) has a new method for taking screenshots. If `extensions.screenshots.disabled` is set to `false` in **about:config**, you can right-click the screen and select **Take Screenshot**. There's also a screenshot menu button you can add to your menu via customization.

You can find some documentation and the full list of commands [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI).

<sub>PS. The screenshots are saved into the *downloads* directory by default.</sub>

Comment: If you want to just copy the screenshot to your clipboard directly use screenshot --clipboard --fullpage

Comment: That command doesn't work in a javascript console, so is there a link to more information about this toolbar? What else can it do?

Comment: Just FYI you can also select DOM notes through the inspector and then `right-click` -> `screenshot node`. This is super helpful when you want to screenshot a section of a page.

Comment: Full page screenshot to clipboard - `screenshot --clipboard --fullpage`
Screenshot of a particular node (by Id) - `screenshot --clipboard --selector #elementId`

Comment: I had to use `:screenshot --clipboard --fullpage` (mind the colon)

Comment: In WaterFox 56.2.6, all I needed to do was press `shift-F2` to open the CLI bar at the bottom of the screen, then I could type `screenshot <filename.png/jpg> --fullpage` and the image was saved to the "Download" folder.  More features are available via this method.

Comment: On MacOS, to open the developer console, I did COMMAND + OPTION + i

Comment: Firefox 88.0 has a new method for taking screenshots. If `extensions.screenshots.disabled` is set to false in about:config, you can right-click the screen and select 'Take Screenshot'. There's also a screenshot menu button you can add to your menu via customization.

Comment: Any cmd line option to open page or take full screenshot of page

Answer (score 143):

**Update 2018-07-23**

As was just pointed out in the comments, this question was about getting a screenshot *from the command line*. Sorry, I just read over that. So here is the correct answer:

As of Firefox 57 you can create a screenshot in headless mode like this:

```
firefox -screenshot https://developer.mozilla.com
```

Read more in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode#Taking_screenshots).

**Update 2017-06-15**

As of Firefox 55 there is [Firefox Screenshots](https://screenshots.firefox.com/) as a more flexible alternative. As of Firefox 57 Screenshots can capture a full page, too.

**Original answer**

Since Firefox 32 there is also a [full page screenshot button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/32) in the developer tools (F12). If it is not enabled go to the developer tools settings (gear button) and choose "Take a fullpage screenshot" at the "Available Toolbox Buttons" section.

[image: developer tools toolbar]
*source: developer.mozilla.org*

By default the screenshots are saved in the download directory. This works similar to `screenshot --fullpage` in the toolbar.

Comment: For those having Firebug opening on F12, the developer tools are available with Ctrl+Shift+K or Ctrl+Shift+I. Just... in case... someone never used them before.

Comment: Those keyboard shortcuts don't work on the Mac. Use Tools > Web Developer > Toggle Tools. And, yes, the screenshot button **is** disabled by default. Click the Settings icon to enable.

Comment: on Mac, you can open the developer tools with `cmd`+`alt`+`i`

Comment: Firefox Screenshots uploads screenshots taken to Mozilla's servers. They did not make this obivous enough for me to notice in advance. Fortunately the image in my case wasn't too sensitive, though it was internal. Be warned.

Comment: @HammerBro. You can click on "download" if you don't want the screenshot to be uploaded to Mozilla's servers. But I agree that the implications of the default behavior is probably not obvious to most users.

Answer (score 9):

I ended up coding a custom solution (Firefox extension) that does this. I think by the time I developed it, the commandline mentioned in enreas wasn't there.

The Firefox extension is [CmdShots](https://github.com/omarabid/CmdShots). It's a good option if you need finer degree of control over the process of taking the screenshot (or you want to do some HTML/JS modifications and image processing).

You can use it and abuse it. I decided to keep it unlicensed, so you are free to play with it as you want.

Comment: Hmm, that's not what "unlicensed" means: it actually means you don't give any permission for any use, which is clearly not true since in that very sentence you also say it's okay to use, abuse, and play with it as you want.  Perhaps you want something like [the CC0](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/legalcode)?

Comment: For those "unlicensed" things I prefer this: http://www.wtfpl.net/ It clearly states what is allowed without legal BS.

Comment: @SamB I randomly stumbled on your comment. Yeah, I know 3 years later. The problem is that if I write a License, I already complicated things. The NOLICENSE approach is to simply stuff.

Comment: Please folks, don't use custom license. I know people try to avoid legal nonsense by writing their own license, but they end up doing the opposite, causing legal head-aches for people as they try to figure out what the custom license actually means. See choosealicense.com

Comment: @SamB - while "unlicensed" isn't explicitly an "official license", "The Unlicense" actually *is* a license, and seems to be pretty close to what the OP describes as his intent for the use of his code. See: https://choosealicense.com/licenses/unlicense/

Answer (score 8):

I think what you are looking for is a utility which enables you to save a **complete** page opened in your browser into a png file. Most probably you are looking for a utility like [commandlineprint2](https://sites.google.com/site/torisugari/commandlineprint2).

After installing the extension, you just need to type the command:

```
firefox -print http://google.com -printfile ~/foo.png
```

Answer (score 3):

[Firefox Screenshots](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-screenshots) is a new tool that ships with Firefox. It is not a developer tool, it is aimed at end-users of the browser.

To take a screenshot, right-click on an empty space on the page, and choose "Take Screenshot". If you then click "Save full page", it will save the full page, scrolling for you.

<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://prod-cdn.sumo.mozilla.net/uploads/gallery/images/2017-10-22-18-49-59-62c92b.png))</sub>

Comment: From the question: "I found many Firefox add-ons, but I'm looking for a solution that can be programmed using the Shell Command line."

Comment: @Quentin this isn't an addon, it's directly integrated in last Firefox versions.

Comment: @Veve — emphasis on "using the Shell Command line"

Comment: I have Firefox 88.0 and don't see the "Take Screenshot" option when right-clicking. I believe this is because, by default, the `extensions.screenshots.disabled` property in about:config is set to `true`. It needs to be set to `false` for that method to work. Otherwise, you need to add the screenshot option. (no restart is required when changing these properties)

Comment: @TylerH You need to right-click on an empty space. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Flimm I did; I clicked all over on multiple different websites. The issue is that property in about:config. As soon as I set it to true, the option appeared in my contextual menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium and the webdriver for Firefox.

```
import selenium.webdriver
import selenium.common

options = selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
# options.headless = True
with selenium.webdriver.Firefox(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get('http://google.com')
    time.sleep(2)
    root=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    root.screenshot('whole page screenshot.png')
```

Comment: missing "import time" from the script, but anyway it worked fine thanks!