# Take screenshots with firefox using command line command

Tags: firefox, command, screenshot

I came across a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158083/take-a-full-page-screenshot-with-firefox) discussing how to take screenshots via firefox and save the file.

None of the solutions there work, since the screenshot feature is already available under the developer tools, is there any way we can use it via the command line?