# How to execute Firefox developer console commands from Selenium?

Tags: selenium, firefox

I would like to execute Firefox's `screenshot --fullpage` command from inside a Selenium java script.

The command is documented in [Take a full page screenshot with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158083/take-a-full-page-screenshot-with-firefox?rq=1)

Is it possible?

Answer (score -2):

You can just take a screenshot from within your Java code. From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423347/8020699

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

[This guy](http://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/how-to-capture-full-page-screenshot-using-selenium-webdriver/) suggests using a library called aShot to take full page screenshots. Here's the link to the [aShot jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/ru/yandex/qatools/ashot/ashot/1.5.3/ashot-1.5.3.jar). Here's the code he gives:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategies;

public class FullPageScreenshot {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        //Modify the path of the GeckoDriver in the below step based on your local system path
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D://Selenium Environment//Drivers//geckodriver.exe");
        // Instantiation of driver object. To launch Firefox browser
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        // To oepn URL "http://softwaretestingmaterial.com"
        driver.get("http://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Screenshot fpScreenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
        ImageIO.write(fpScreenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new File("D:///FullPageScreenshot.png"));
    }
}
```

Comment: But `Not_in_(granted it's in python)` its `Java`. Thanks

Comment: aShot is a bit unreliable (gets stuck on some pages) and not as nice (unwanted repetition of 'fixed' elements) when compared to the built-in `screenshot --fullpage` command in the Firefox console