# Capturing and saving a screen shot

Tags: java, screenshot, yahoo-finance

To save an image from the web in a folder?

I was thinking a behind the scenes screen shot or something.  The image I am trying to get is at this link:
http://finance.yahoo.com/charts?s=CLF#chart5:symbol=clf;range=20010429,20040901;charttype=line;crosshair=off;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined

Yahoo allows you to get just the chart of a specific symbol using something like this: http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/c/3m/d/msft , but i need to be able to specify the range of the chart.

Im looking for this to be done in java.

Comment: FYI: You are talking about saving a rendered web page as an image, not taking a 'screenshot' in the traditional sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this SO question: [Convert web page to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image)

Search around for phrases like ["render web page to image"](http://www.google.com/search?q=render%20web%20page%20to%20image) - that should help you more than searching info about 'screenshots'.