# Save HTML inside div as image

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I've got a div where the user has dropped different image elements. They have also rotated, resized and changed opacity. All is done with CSS and the styles are placed inline on each element inside the div. I now need a way to save the "artwork" as a picture. I'm using CSS3 so the rendering-engine that converts HTML to image has to support this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert web page to image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image)

Comment: Do you want to write the software yourself or use a third party application?

Comment: I dont mind writing some code my self but a third party application would be the best solution. Maybe CutyCapt is something I should try.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using CSS3 anyway, it's probably safe to also use the new Canvas API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

You can use getImageData() to save to bitmap.