# Form to image with php

Tags: php, image, converters

I want to take a picture from a form like this

http://users.atw.hu/onlinemoney/news.php and then you click to `prrof - x` then you get a picture

http://users.atw.hu/onlinemoney/proof/tulipptc_1.jpg

How can I imitate this using PHP ?

Comment: You're not asking a specific-enough question to be answered. Are you trying to learn how to handle uploaded files?

Comment: I am getting a Bitdefender Malware warning on the onlinemoney/news.php link given above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write something to images.
Try PHP-GD or PHP-Imagick.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

But I guess you are trying to convert a html page (a form?) to image. See this topic to find answer:

[Convert web page to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image)