# Convert div(Part of webpage) to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to capture a part of web page as image, programmatically, i.e., using Javascript or JQuery. I have tried with [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/#/documentation.html), but it is not working when I have swf objects and iframes.

My web page may contain swf file(Fusion charts), iframes, text, and images. I'm trying to convert all the objects into a single image. Does anyone know a possible solution, that works also on IE9?

Comment: You can't do that. flash is not part of html, javascript has no way to capture that.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image

Answer (score 2):

Setup a virtual machine which reads a list of websites to capture

```
wget ...
```

every now and then

```
/etc/crontab
```

let it open an url

```
firefox http://....
```

and then take a screenshot from a second shell

```
import -window root /home/ftp/screenshots_<id>.jpg
```

then close firefox instance / shell and loop  that for all your urls

This can all be put into 1 shell script and loaded into a very small virtual box,
use `awesome-wm` or some tiny window manager. Also `import` needs `imagemagick`.

This is the only way you can capture html and flash and iframes like rendered by the browser in an hidden automatic process.