# How to get background color of a site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, phantomjs

Let me explain. I am not looking for a particular attribute of a particular DOM element. I started thinking that if I checked the `background-color` of the **body** element, I would find the background color of a page.

But for example for this site: [performance bikes](http://www.performancebike.com/bikes/Product_10052_10551_1135340_-1_1830021__1830021) the background color of body is **black**, and it's "obvious" that the main background color of the site is **white**.

So, I am parsing the site with **PhantomJS**. What do you think would be a good strategy to be able to find the most "visible" background-color. I don't know how to say that, but for a human it is kind of obvious which color is the background. How to find it programatically?

EDIT: the bikes site is just an example. I am thinking on how I would do this for "any" page.

Comment: No where on that website does it say the background is black besides the main nav. There is no main background and that is why it has a white background, by default. On the `body` tag the `color` is indeed black but that is for text.

Comment: Usually backgrounds are containers of other elements, an approach would be finding the biggest container and uses its color, but your problem isn't simple at all.

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve? Why do you want to do this programmatically?

Comment: @Pointy experimenting on creating a sum up of a page in a PNG. Extracting some info, and I would like the background to be "familiar" with the page. By familiar I mean the most visible background.

Comment: What if the background is an image?

Comment: How about generating X,Y coordinate pairs at random, then use document.elementFromPoint() to get the front-most element at X,Y.  Grab it's computed background-color, rinse and repeat to create a bucket of samples, and take the most frequent occurrence.  Hacky? yes.  Other solutions? probably hacky as well.  Image background? you're toast, anyway...

Comment: The downvoters could tell me the reason of why downvote?

Comment: The bikes site has a yellow background in my Firefox. This is because I deliberately set a non-white default background so I get reminded to always set an explicit background colour on my own sites. (The point being that the correct answer here is perhaps "null"...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background color of the Performance bikes site *is* `transparent`. However, because of some weird reason, they decided to make the whole main `div` to be `absolute` position, therefore, the `body` tag is `1px` high and thus showing the default white color. One idea I have is, you can check if the `body`'s height is less than some percentage of the window. If it is too small, then it probably is `white`, or `transparent` for some special browsers.

Alternatives including [taking a screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image) of the page and determine the background color from it.

Comment: Where are you seeing that it says it is black? This `color: #333333;` is for text color and on the `body id="xyz` and `#mainPage` have no `background`/`background-color` on it.

Comment: No problem, it seems like everyone is. :]

Comment: Derek, say I have a screenshot... How would I find the background color? Pixel by pixel and counting colors of each of them?

Comment: @HommerSmith Open up photoshop and use the eyedropper tool. :p

Comment: @HommerSmith - Well actually it depends on how you define "background" color. Take [this page](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/policy-pricing/customer-alert.html?promoid=KHQGF) for example, is white the background color or gray?

Comment: Gray :) It's background the white and it is visible... Even though in this case both white and gray would be acceptable. It's hard to know how to define most 'visible' background-color.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 that website's color is the rainbow. :}

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 :D - I am parsing major product websites. The colors are usually straight (nothing against that Mario Bross background-color though)

Comment: @HommerSmith - I suggest that you can take something like ten pixels, five per side, at the very edge of the left and right side. Most of the time the background color will appear there.

Comment: Derek, when taking a picture of that site (performancebikes), I see the background transparent.

Comment: @HommerSmith - If it is background is transparent, then I think the browser will usually apply the default white, however it is [not always the case](http://files.myopera.com/Kastelang/blog/2011-05-28_172507.png).

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and check which of the layers is on top, also the width and height of that div, then just grab its background-color property.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

Not perfect, but should return you the element with the biggest area and make sure that it is visible.  Won't account for it being below other elements, but it's a start...

```
var element={
    width:0,
    height:0,
    color:'',
    jQEl:{}
}

$('*:visible').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var area = element.width*element.height;
    var thisArea = $this.width()*$this.height();
    if(thisArea>area){
        element.width = $this.width();
        element.height= $this.height();
        element.color=$this.css('background-color');
        element.jQEl=$this;
    }
});

console.log(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a screenshot, then make a histogram of the image to find the most common colour.

Refinements:

- First go through and replace all text content with "& nbsp;"
- Give extra weight to the pixels closest to the edge of the screen.

(To automate entirely within PhantomJS, you might be able to use something like http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ to use a canvas, and never need to make an external image file.)

Answer (score -1):

Another nice solution is to use browser plug-ins. I use Eye Dropper for chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eye-dropper/hmdcmlfkchdmnmnmheododdhjedfccka?hl=en

Or you can use colorPicker for Firefox. To get it, in your firefox browser, goto:

Tools -> Add-ons -> top right search bar look for "colorPicker"

It's 10 times faster to find the color of a background on a site this way than searching through the CSS code.

Comment: This is horrible answer...how hard is it to just right-click, "inspect element" and view the CSS? lol

Comment: @HommerSmith If you need a complex function to find colors within an image and DOM elements then you need to do a lot of research or find a  function that someone made.

Comment: @MikeBarwick The only plus that I see to this answer is you can not just inspect an images colors.

Comment: @MikeBarwick well if an element has a gradient applied across it with CSS, or if the element is translucent and lays over another element with a different color, the CSS won't tell you much.

Comment: Huh? lol Same thing. For each live website you can get every single CSS function...gradients are applied with the same background css element..so I don't understand you question.