# Have a screen shot taken of a certain page in a specific time interval and stored on same server

Tags: php, apache, webpage-screenshot

I currently have a php script which displays real time information and is updated whenever the page is refreshed ( it is automatically refreshed every 30 minutes ). Is there a php script or something server side which will have it screen shot the updated page and store it on the server?

I am using the latest version of apache on a Linux Centos Server.

Regards,

John

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux

Comment: @MLore that's a duplicate but it's also closed. There are some good answers on this closed one though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image

Comment: The closing of those questions seems harsh and counterproductive. I think it's a legitimate thing to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium has PHP bindings and can take a screenshot. It's very powerful but also requires some setup effort. Selenium uses an actual web browser to do its work, so the screenshot will accurately reflect HTML5 and other types of dynamic content.