# Convert TinyMCE value to an image

Tags: php, tinymce

Is there any way in php that the value from a TinyMce input box can be converted into an image once it is posted and collected. This would need to include the style of font, colour, size etc that the user has chosen.

This would of course be completed on the server side and I am wondering if there is anything out there that would do this. The server is a Debian Linux based running Ubuntu Server 12.04

Many thanks

P

Comment: from what i have seen it is converted to html Example bold shows with the tag strong and italic shows with the tag em

Comment: So you essentially want a program that converts html tags and styles to a static image. In order to prevent highlighting and other similar actions.

Comment: Hi Logan that would be correct

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image

Comment: Many thanks, I will take a look at the links shown in that thread