# Dynamically convert section of WordPress page into image

Tags: html, image, wordpress

Been going crazy trying to figure this out.

So basically, I have this page built in WordPress: 
http://www.allaroundmath.com/tempe-schedule-test/

What I would like to do is find a way to export what's in the blue and grey table (built with the Visual Composer plugin) into an image, so that it is easily printable.

Ideally, this would happen when clicking on the Print-Friendly Version button (which right now just leads to a .jpg I created with Photoshop).

I've tried using print stylesheets to just recreate what's on the page when printing, but that is not working for some reason (perhaps an issue with Visual Composer).

A way to export the page into PDF form while keeping the page styling would also be an acceptable solution.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I appreciate any feedback regardless.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image) is related, have you seen that? I would try and get the print stylesheet going before looking for an HTML/CSS/JS to PNG/ JPG solution. Also, could it be that this question is better suited over at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ? Have you asked the Visual Composer support if they have issues with printing the sites composed with their tool? I find this question interesting and am curious about a solution.