# webpage screenshot khtml2png alternatives

Tags: linux, png, webpage-screenshot

Are there any alternatives to khtml2png ie. command line tools to create png screenshots of webpages? 
I would like to run it on a server to grab snapshots of certain sites.

Linux only please. webkit2png is pretty awesome on osx...

Thanks!

Comment: multiple question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/

see this

with python

```
python /path/to/webkit2png http://www.google.com/
```

also you can do it with firefox !?

```
  firefox -savepng http://www.web-screen-capture.com/
```

Comment: webkit2png is mac os x only. I found http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/ and http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mashape.com/warting/scrapegoat/

You just need curl

I know I'm a bit late but maybe it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice command line tool called *gnome-web-photo*. Usage is simple as this:

```
gnome-web-photo http://google.com myscreenshot.png
```