# Getting screenshots of web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webpage-screenshot

I have a website that i need to add a function that every time the user navigates to another page a screenshot of the page should be taken so i can use them latter.

I need this to be automatically done, with out the user doing any thing.

I do prefer not to have the user install any thing on his computer, if possible.

my site is written in asp.net, c# and regular web languages (jquery...).

Does any one have any good ides of ways to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Surely there is FAQ item for this by now http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=website+thumbnail

Comment: You can do this with imageMagick, do you have root access to your server?

Comment: @Faraona, yes i have access, how do i use this? (i need it to be automatically )

Comment: Check link in my POST down. If you want to do this automatically, the best way is to create cronjob script who will process websites and take screenshoot

Comment: @Faraona How do i do that? with the link you put in your POST? what is a cronjob script ?

Comment: Here you are another example [link](http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/website_screenshot.htm)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i would use [`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx).DrawToBitmap

Comment: -1 He want's a screenshot of the current page, and that class is only available in Windows Forms, in the tag he specifies ASP.NET, your idea is to load the page inside the `WebBrowser` control, there is no such control in an ASP.NET application!

Comment: that means i cant use this in my asp.net application?

Comment: asp.net apps runns with full .Net framework. this namespace is available. If you have FullTrust this isn't a problem. (I know: it's dirty to use classes of System.Forms in web apps).

Comment: I dont understand how to use this class to do what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons **Web pages have no access to users hardware** through normal processes.

You can create and ask the user to install an ActiveX object (IE only) or use a Java Applet (all browsers).

**FogBugz** is a Online Bug Report and they offer a way of doing a screndump directly to a Bug Id, but you still need to install the client application to do just that.

You can also use Silverlight as that requests user permission to access some of the hardware, like Audio, Screen, Printers, etc...

Answer (score -1):

If you have root access to your server you can do this: [LINK](http://corpocrat.com/2008/08/26/capturing-a-screenshot-of-a-website/)

And then create your script (cronjob) to execute it.

Answer (score -1):

Here you are another way to do this: [Command line program to create website screenshots (on Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux)

[**What is cronjob and how you can use it**](http://service.futurequest.net/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=30)