# Create Screen Shot of web page that user is visting in our site

Tags: php, image

I have to create screen shot of web page that user is visiting in our site, through PHP. I have testing many script, working well when I pass URL of live site like google etc, But i have to create screen shoot of page that the user is visiting in our site.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible via PHP, you'd have to trigger a system event to open a browser and take a screenshot or have service installed on a machine specifically aimed at doing this.. It's a lot more involved than coding something up in PHP.

[Command line program to create website screenshots (on Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks tom... But in my case i can't use third party web services nor command line programs. I have to code by myself, how much time it takes ???

Comment: Creating all of these things yourself just isn't feasible, you'd need a strong knowledge in other areas such as a C based language. Or you can focus on using something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php for executing command line via PHP. I'd then recommend looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux in an attempt to replicate via PHP.