# PHP - Extract image from video (online)

Tags: php, image, video, extract

How can i extract image from video that's playing all the time.

I mean that there is a video that playing all the time (now, in the future and allways), I'm looking for a way to extract a picture from this video at this moment for example.

Is it even possible using PHP ?

Comment: If the video is web based this might be useful,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using Using a command-line tool like the popular ffmpeg executed from the php script.